# Problem with node being "commissioning" and doesn't change to "ready"

Tags: 13.04, juju, maas

I got a machine up and running 13.04. I followed the instruction and set up MAAS. Current state I need nodes to be in "ready" state, so that I can install juju with MAAS. However, the nodes are stuck in "commissioning" state. 
I checked the clocks in each node, and they all synchronize well.

I also tried "$ maas-cli maas nodes accept-all" for Automatic Discovery
I am not sure how to fix this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you are hitting this bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+bug/1131418

Comment: does this mean that my installation of maas is correct, but I need to set tags or define tags? If so, nodes won't change to "ready" states until I do "$ juju deploy --constraints maas-tags=gpu cuda" ??
Thank you

Comment: is using tag necessary when goal is to use juju with maas?

Comment: No tags are not really necessary. Tags are simply a way to identify systems, so you can easily obtain one when deploying. If all your nodes are equal I don't see why you would need to make use of tags.

Answer (score 0):

Bounce your nodes. I was stuck on this for almost a week. Your servers aren't responding to the "Wake On LAN" or whatever "remote"method you are trying to use to wake up the servers.

After you setup your MAAS controller, you "power-on" your servers. If DHCP/DNS is setup right, they PXE boot and load a version of the OS that is used for "Declaring" the server to the MAAS controller. At that point they show up in your "Nodes" list as declared. You select the server and click on "Accept and Commission"...then they stay there, never changing. For me, this meant that the PXE command to boot to the new "commissioning" OS was IGNORED by my servers. I simply turned them on and voila....about 10 minutes later, they are completely configured and "Ready".

Comment: Yes and no.  My Dell Vostro's were fine with WOL throughout... except for one step in the commissioning.  At the part where the new OS is installed and it then needs to restart it powered down instead.  If you're then watching along with a monitor installed if you simply then power on the node it will then finish a full commission and go to the Ready status.  It's not that WOL isn't working--the preseed step after the OS install seems to have a bug.